# I want to create an API JSON Structure for post parameters in swift

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, parameters

I want to create a nested JSON for using it as a Post method parameter. I tried NSDictionary, Array, [String:Any], etc. But failed to get the accurate JSON structure.
I want a JSON format, like this

```
    {
  "Command": [
    {
      "commandData": {
        "name": "name",
        "description": "description",
        "title": "title",
        "actions": [
          {
            "ERR": [
              {
                "ERR_LINE": {
                  "Value": {
                    "1": 1.0,
                    "2": 1.0,
                    "3": 1.0,
                    "4": 1.0,
                    "5": 1.0,
                    "6": 1.0
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "errID": "id",
      "issueID": "id"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
var postData = Dictionary<String,Any>()

postData = [

"Command": [

    "commandData": [

        "name": "name",

        "description": "description",

        "title": "title",

        "actions": [

            "ERR": [

                "ERR_LINE": [
                  "Value": [
                    "1": 1.0,
                    "2": 1.0,
                    "3": 1.0,
                    "4": 1.0,
                    "5": 1.0,
                    "6": 1.0
                  ]
                ]
            ]  
        ]
    ],
  "errID": "id",
  "issueID": "id"
  ]
]
```

Hope it works.